# Error al cargar el APK de una aplicación expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apk, expo, build

Hace poco genere el APK de una aplicación móvil en la que estoy trabajando, la aplicación es hecha en react native y expo, en lenguaje js, el APK se descarga sin ningún problema en los dispositivos pero a la hora de abrirlo de manera instantánea se cierra, para generar el APK corri el comando "eas build -p android --profile preview", intente cambiando la configuración pero tampoco me da resultado

Comment: Puede que se cierre porque crashea. Intenta ver el error que da tu app en producción. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72321991/17127043